# Sharepoint Designer Email Lookup Semicolon Delimited not available

Tags: sharepoint-designer, email, workflow-lookup

I have following situation:
I have a Custom List with Attendees with two columns: User (which gets automatically filled with a user) and MeetingID (also autofilled)

Now I have a Discussion board which has a DiscussionID which matches a MeetingID.
I want to send an email with a link to a thread to all users, where the DiscussionID and MeetingID matches.

I created a list workflow on the discussion board list. Here I chose the action "Send an Email". In the To I selected "Workflow Lookup for a User..."

Data Source: Attendees
Field from source: User
Return field as: Email adress

Find the list item:
Field: MeetingID
Value: Current Item:DiscussionID

of course this gives back multiple values but it only sends an email to the first user. I need to seperate the adresses with semicolons I guess but I don't understand why at Return field as there is no option Semicolon Delimited.

Any help or workaround for this? :)